# substitution of variables with input command

Tags: bash, variables

```
#!/bin/sh

own1="jack"
own2="mark"
own3="black"
    read n "insert number [1-3]"
    echo $own{n}
```

the purpose is substitution own[1-3] variable with new n variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use an *indirect variable* (documented in the 4th paragraph of [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))

```sh
varname="own$n"
echo "${!varname}"
```

Or in bash version 4.3+, use a *nameref*

```sh
declare -n name="own$n"
echo "$name"
```

But this is much easier with arrays:

```sh
own=(jack mark black)              # an array with 3 elements
read -p "insert number [1-3] " n   # use `-p` option to set the prompt

# TODO validate n is actually a number in the correct range

# bash arrays are zero-indexed, so
echo "${own[n - 1]}"
```

For elememnts of a numerically indexed array, the index is an arithmetic expression.

However, to ask the user to select one of a number of options, use the `select` command:

```sh
own=(jack mark black)
PS3="Choose a name: "
select name in "${own[@]}"; do
  [[ -n $name ]] && break
done
echo "you chose $name"
```